# Adding values of 2 columns from a matrice and putting the sum in a vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

My first question about CPP in Stackoverflow. I hope i get an answer.

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream fin("Matr.dat");
ofstream fout("out.dat");

int a[1000][1000];
int b[10000];
int n, m;
void read()
{
    fin>>n>>m;
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<m; j++)
            fin>>a[i][j];
    }
}
int vect()
{
    int c=1;
    for(int i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=2; j<=m; j++)
        {
            b[c]=a[j]+a[j+1];
            c++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int main()
{

    read();
    int c=vect();
    for(int i=0; i<c; i++)
        fout<<b[i]<<' ';
    return 0;
}
```

I and a colleague are trying to add the values of 2 columns into a vector.
For the line `b[c]=a[j]+a[j+1]; i receive an error saying that i use 2 incompatible types together. It is not working...

Can someone please help me add the values of 2 columns into a vector?

Comment: Be careful with the names you choose to explain your problem. These are not matrices and vectors. Those are array and array of array. They sadly *do no* map to those mathematical concepts. A good math library that offer those vector and matrices types might help you a lot.

Comment: What do you think `a[j]` is? Please remember how `a` is declared. Shouldn't it be `a[i][j]` instead (or `a[j][i]`, depending on what you do want to sum)?

Comment: Also, please note that, in C++, array indices start from zero.

Comment: `for(int i=1; i<n; i++)` looks odd. `i=1` means nothing will be stored in `a[0][X]`. Maybe this is exactly what you want, but to me it looks like an off-by-one error.

Comment: Similarly in `for(int i=2; i<=n; i++)`, `i<=n`, will allow `i` to equal `n`, and that could be an off by one error in the other direction.